# How to make a slider with that functionality (html, css, js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

[refrence](https://fxhome.com/hitfilm-express/pwyw).
i want to make a slider that highlights (making it bigger, but i know how to do it) a card once its value is X (e.g. 20). the faces on the slider there aren't necessary, i need to understand the core functionality using html, css and js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple function to do some actions base on input value can be like this :

```js
    document.getElementById("myRange").addEventListener("change", function (e) {
      let value = parseInt(this.value);
      let resultElm = document.getElementById("result");
      switch (true) {
        case 0 < value && value <= 20:
          resultElm.innerHTML = ":|";
          break;
        case 20 < value && value <= 40:
          resultElm.innerHTML = ":)";
          break;
        case 40 < value && value <= 60:
          resultElm.innerHTML = ":))";
          break;
        case 60 < value && value <= 80:
          resultElm.innerHTML = ":D";
          break;
        case 80 < value && value <= 100:
          resultElm.innerHTML = "^^";
          break;
      }
    });
```

```html
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="myRange" />
    <div id="result"></div>
```

you can do whatever you want inside the `case blocks` , highlight something , change an icon or etc ...